# Multiple Image slider on one page using JQuery

Tags: jquery, carousel, caroufredsel

I've seen several related issues but I'm still trying to understand them. So while testing it, I thought of posting this question hoping someone may see it and give some light.

My goal is to use the same (one) jquery script for image slider for different categories using different blocks in Drupal which will ALL appear on homepage. Thus,

Block1 - contains image slider for category 1
Block2 - contains image slider for category 2
Block3 - contains image slider for category 3

and so on..

I was able to create different blocks already but the page only refreshes each time I try to click the next arrow.

My JS which I got from http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/ is below:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            $('#carousel ul').carouFredSel({
                prev: '#prev',
                next: '#next',
                pagination: "#pager",
                scroll: 500,
                auto: false
            });

        });
    </script>
           <script src="jquery.carouFredSel-6.0.4-packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

HTML is:

```
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="carousel">
            <ul>
            <li><a href=""><img src="" width="100px"/></a><span>Image1</span></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="" width="100px"/></a><span>Image2</span></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="" width="100px"/></a><span>Image3</span></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="" width="100px"/></a><span>Image4</span></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="" width="100px"/></a><span>Image5</span></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="" width="100px"/></a><span>Image6</span></li>

            </ul>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>

            <a id="next" class="next" href="#">&gt;</a>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks guys in advance.

Comment: do you have the caroufredsel pluggin.. it is the script of that pluggin...

Comment: @Jaimin MosLake. I updated the issue above. I noticed I didn't include the issue.

Comment: if i understand it right.. you need three sliders for three differnt places... assume one at header ,, second in body and third at footer ... means it will be in three different divs or uls......?  m i understanding correct...? sliders in thress different divs or uls ...?

Comment: u need three different divs or uls id and ... threee script for each one...and 3*2=6 next prev buttons

Comment: yes, you're right. i already used different ids, example #carousel1, #carousel2 for each category. They are also inside different divs. As a matter for fact, I'm using that script and HTML (where images only change for each category/block)

Comment: so just u need to write this script three times.. with different ids and other respective id's of ur slider like next prev buttons... if its not helpful then see console.. may be error is another...

Comment: yes, you're right. I already did that but it's not rendering correctly. I read somewhere about jQuery noconflict? that might be an issue?

Comment: And from your previous comment, are you confirming that the same script can be added on one page? How about calling of the plugin? <script src="jquery.carouFredSel-6.0.4-packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script> Should it be present on all blocks?

Comment: try with only one... if it renders correct .. then three will also render... so if one renders then there is no issue of jquery conflict...

Comment: i was able to make the first carousel work (in one block) but when I try to add the second, the images of carousel2 moves when the next arrow of carousel1 is clicked. Anyways, I'll try again, might be an issue on css. But it's a good thing that you dig in and somehow confirm that I can use the same script.

Comment: Hi! Again. This is a visual presentation of what's happening - http://screencast.com/t/g6VUJMP9k1Jy and this is the message from the Firebug Console http://screencast.com/t/2pIMrsmJy - They have different divs. What am I missing?

Comment: for prev next buttons... use buttons instead of a .... it will stop from refreshing

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
// Using default configuration
$('#moreVideos_carousel').carouFredSel();

// Using custom configuration
$('#moreVideos_carousel').carouFredSel({
    circular: true,    
    items               : 3,
    direction           : "left",
    scroll : {
        items           : 3,
        easing          : "elastic",
        duration        : 1000,                         
        pauseOnHover    : true
    },     
    prev    : {
    button  : "#morevideos_prev",
    key     : "left"
    },
    next    : {
    button  : "#morevideos_next",
    key     : "right"
 },                   
});



$('#relatedShows_carousel').carouFredSel();

// Using custom configuration
$('#relatedShows_carousel').carouFredSel({
    circular: true,    
    items               : 3,
    direction           : "left",
    scroll : {
        items           : 3,
        easing          : "elastic",
        duration        : 1000,                         
        pauseOnHover    : true
    },     
    prev    : {
    button  : "#relatedShows_prev",
    key     : "left"
    },
    next    : {
    button  : "#relatedShows_next",
    key     : "right"
 },                   
  });
 });
 </script>
```

here you can see i've used two different carousel ... and it needs two different divs, + 4 different buttons or a's for next and previous buttons ...

```
first carousel  
#moreVideos_carousel
prev btn - #morevideos_prev
next btn - #morevideos_next


second carpousel
#relatedShows_carousel
prev btn - #relatedShows_prev
next btn - #relatedShows_next
```

you have to have like this...

Comment: i won't be using the prev button. this should be a continuous slides going to the right. I'm still understanding your code since I'm new to Jquery. Thank you so much

Comment: if it helps then please upVote... and if its correct then correct it... needing high reputation badly...

Comment: I'm still trying to follow since your script is completely different from my example. I'll vote after I confirm it's working. Thank you